# I am not able to display data in Ionic view while I am calling my php API

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to display data using a php API. My php side is complete and is displaying data when I use `echo`. That said, when I try to fetch it in my Ionic view with `http.get` it gives me an error.

**feed.ts**

```
posts: any;
constructor(
            public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, 
            public http: Http
           ) 
{
    this.http.get( 'https://schoolinformation.000webhostapp.com/phpapi.php' )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
               this.posts = data.data;
               console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
               console.log("Oops!");
            }
        );
}
```

**feed.html**

```
<ng-container>
    <div id="question" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <div id="questionaksedby">Question Aksked:{{posts.type}}</div>
        <br>
        <div id="Question"><b></b></div>
        <br>
        <div id="questiontime">Last asked:</div>
        <br> 
        <div id="answerbtn"><button class="btn-lg">Answer</button> Follow:</div>

     </div>
 </ng-container>
```

error:

[image]

Comment: What error does it give you? Probably unrelated, but ids in html should be unique, so you shouldnt use them in a loop

Comment: first of all it is going direct in else part means it is print "opps" and when i remove this code "map(res => res.json())" it will give me error like this

Comment: and when i remove this code "map(res => res.json())" it will give me error like this =>>"Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://schoolinformation.000webhostapp.com/phpapi.php' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Replace `console.log("Oops!");` with `console.log(err);` and add the error to your question.

Comment: now its is showing error like this ==>>  "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1"

Answer (score 0):

it seems that data is not coming from php api. Or its may be due to url so check the url too that you have passed in your ionic get method.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I see it is the first time you answer on this site, congratulations. A good question is 90% of the answer but this question is very low quality. It is hard to give a good answer to a bad question, for example your answer would fit a comment just as well.